# Why does my calendar start a day late in december?

Tags: javascript

I'm supposed to build a calendar with only html, css, and javascript - no php, no jquery, nothing. I have been working on a bug in my code all weekend, but I don't know where it comes from. I don't know what to do. This is my code:

```
"use strict";

window.onload = init;

function init() {
    var day = new Date();
    var month = day.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = day.getYear() + 1900;
    var next = document.getElementById("next");
    var previous = document.getElementById("previous");

    next.onclick = nextMonth(month);
    previous.onclick = previousMonth(month);

    generateCalendar(month, year);
}

function generateCalendar(_month, _year) {
    var table = document.getElementById("calendar");

    var month = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni",
    "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"];
    var day = ["Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa", "So"];
    var totaldays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

    //determining the first day of the month
    var firstday = new Date(_year, _month + 1, 1);
    var start = firstday.getDay() + 1;


    var end = totaldays[_month - 1]; //determining the length of the month

    //February
    if (end === totaldays[1]) {
        //leap years (% means modulo)
        if ((_year % 4 === 0 && _year % 100 !== 0) || _year % 400 === 0) {
            end = 29;
        }
    }

    //tale header
    var head = month[_month - 1] + " " + _year;
    var caption = table.createCaption();
    caption.innerHTML = head;

    var cell;
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    for (var i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        cell = row.insertCell(i);
        cell.innerHTML = day[i];
    }

    var days = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) { //started week in a month
        row = table.insertRow(i + 1);

        for (var j = 0; j <= 6; j++) { //days of a week

            //regular calendar days
            if (days <= end && (i > 0 || j >= start)) {
                cell = row.insertCell(j);
                cell.innerHTML = days;
                days++;
            } else {

                //Days that aren't in the current month are shown as empty
                cell = row.insertCell(j);
                cell.innerHTML = "";
            }
        }
    }
}


function nextMonth(_month) {
    //contruction site
}

function previousMonth(_month) {
    //construction site
}
```

My `html` file pretty much only has a `<table>` with the `id` named above.

So the calendar is in **German** obviously. As you can see (I hope) I tried to put the first day of the month on a field in an `array` from 0-6 for my week days which is very basic and it works!

Until December. The first day of December is supposed to be a Friday, but in my calendar it's on a Saturday and I have no idea why it jumps a day ahead. I debugged it and all I see is it skips a day in my array. I suppose it has something to do with the `+1` at `firstday.getDay()` but I need that because all the `Date` functions are so inconsistent.

Comment: getDay is 0-6 indexed, where 0 is Sunday. Adding 1 will shift everything one day ahead, just as you're seeing.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: Also, you need to subtract instead of adding 1 to month here: `var firstday = new Date(_year, _month + 1, 1);` - i.e. that should be `new Date(_year, _month - 1, 1)`

Comment: Thank you KG Christensen and searlea. I thought I could "trick" Date by shifting my week with +1. Obviously I was wrong. As for the +1/-1 thing. That must be a leftover of my "trying to fix" because it used to be -1. Good thing you noticed because I probably wouldn't have.